# Storing values for a set of DOM's nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose that I have the following HTML code

```
...
<div class="c">
  <p><strong>foo</strong></p>
  <p>Hello, World</p>
  <ol><li>Element</li></ol>
  <p><strong>bar</strong></p>
  <p><strong>foobar</strong></p>
</div>
...
```

and that I want to fill three variables with the text wrapped by tags of kind

```
<p><strong>...</strong><p>
```

How can I do that, using jQuery?

Course, it's easy for two of them, via

```
foo = $( ".c p strong" ).first().text();
foobar = $( ".c p strong" ).last().text();
```

but what happens when I have more than two elements?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map` and `get` to get an array of strings:

```
var foos = $(".c p > strong").map(function(i, el){
    return $(el).text();
}).get();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pJV4v/